# How to run jquery validate() while using form wizard?

Tags: jquery, validation, formwizard

I am using the [jQuery Form Wizard 3.0.4 plugin](http://thecodemine.org/#_demoForm=first) for a multistep registration process. It uses the jQuery validator plugin built in, which is working fine when going from step to step. **EDIT**: This means I am already using validationEnabled: true, formOptions,  and validationOptions, and these are working. I need to run this same validation outside of the regular functionality.

The problem is that I need to run the validator and show errors manually at two points. For a special field I have, and before an AJAX submission. I've tried the following, which does nothing:

```
$("#registrationForm").validate();
```

The form wizard script (jquery.form.wizard-3.0.4.js) appears to be doing this when going to the next step:

```
this.element.validate().focusInvalid();
```

So I tried this, which also does nothing:

```
$("#registrationForm").element.validate().focusInvalid();
```

Any ideas?

1. How do I run the same validation that occurs when I click next step?
2. How would I call a function that validates and shows errors for a specific field?

Comment: Is it possible and feasible to use jquery formwizard plugin in JQM pages? If so, will it be too heavy for mobile page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the example code below should probably work for you, the validation is triggered when the button or element with id="validate_form" is clicked. This is basically the code that is run (in the plugin) when the user clicks next.

```
    $(function(){
        $("#validate_form").click(function(){ // when the button is clicked...
            var wizard = $("#demoForm"); // cache the form element selector
            if(!wizard.valid()){ // validate the form
                wizard.validate().focusInvalid(); //focus the invalid fields
            }

        })
    })
```

If you would just need to validate one single input field then you could use the following code (the button with id="validate_email" is clicked in this case):

```
    $(function(){
        $("#validate_email").click(function(){ // when the button is clicked...
            var wizard = $("#demoForm"); // cache the form element selector
            if(!wizard.validate().element( "#myemail" )){ // validate the input field
                wizard.validate().focusInvalid(); // focus it if it was invalid
            }

        })
    })
```

Hope this helps.

/Jan

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the plugin's documentation? There's a simple switch in the setup that will enable you to do that kind of validation when you're defining your form wizard.

http://thecodemine.org/#_demoForm=first

Then click on "Options" and look at the 'validationEnabled' to enable validation and then look at 'validationOptions' to setup your options.

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing that: "It uses the jQuery validator plugin built in, which is working fine when going from step to step."